# Backup-spsite Restore-spsite user permissions

Tags: permissions, backup, restore

I have run a Backup-spsite and then a Restore-spsite from a development farm to a production one. The permissions set on the development farm have not been carried to production.

The site collection admins were not set correctly. The site collection permissions were set by no to the correct user:

Instead of domain\username it was recorded as i:0.w|domain\username.

When assigning people permission they do not seem to work. Users who had perms in the last site now have two entries in the select user list.

Very confused!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you changing authentication methods between the two farms? It sounds like your production farm has Claims Based Authentication setup and your dev is using classic.

Comment: How can I cehck to see the authication taht a web application has?

Comment: In Central Admin > Manage Web Applications (under Application Management) > Select Web App, click Authentication Providers. This will list all zones setup, with their associated authentication.

Comment: Youa are correct they are differnt. I will recreate the production web app to be claims based. If this solves the problem will mark the answer as correct.

Comment: Just to confirm all working fine now